# How to determine hardware?

Tags: command-line, hardware, diagnostic

Is there a command to detect the type of processor, type of graphics card, type of hard drive, just the basic hardware my computer is running?

I'm running 12.04.

Comment: For my Acer Travelmate-P243-M, the following works well (others don't show my wireless hardware info in full): `$ lspci -vv` However, there are many other options beautifully presented here: [https://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-hardware-info/](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-hardware-info/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can easily find this most of this information out with the dmidecode command:

```
sudo dmidecode -q
```

It may be a little verbose though. To find out information about a specific device, you can use the `-t` type argument. More information on that is here, http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/how-to-get-hardware-information-on-linux-using-dmidecode-command/

Another option would be to use lshw

```
sudo lshw
```

To find out the disk usage of your hard drive, you can use the df command:

```
sudo df -h
```

Comment: I don't see anything about my video card on there is it because I don't have one or what?

I have an AMD processor and ATI graphics. I would put the output here but its too long.

Comment: Try this `sudo lshw -C display` That should just display your video card. Your video card should be displayed.

Comment: Also, if something has a lot of output, you can use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ to post it.

Comment: I don't see where to mark it as solved.

Comment: @TerNovi You use the "checkmark" icon as shown in [this screenshot](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png). (But then you appear to have already figured that out.) A suggestion: when a comment is no longer relevant, just delete it to help eliminate clutter from your question.

Answer (score 8):

This command will tell you about your hardware (including the specific components you've listed):

```
sudo lshw
```

It's possible to run `lshw` without `sudo` (i.e., not as `root`) but it may not give as complete or accurate information.

You can run `lshw` with the `-C` flag and an argument, to get information about a specific class of hardware. See [`man lshw`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lshw.1.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `lspci`, possibly filtering its output with `grep` (look for `VGA` or `video` keywords for GPU information), for example try:

```
$ lspci -v | grep VGA
```

See `man lspci` and also http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tell-which-graphics-vga-card-installed/

Answer (score 0):

"dmidecode" is a handy native linux command which gives many hardware details. I've written a script to get all the details and if someone is interested can check out here:

[How To Get Hardware Info](http://simplylinuxfaq.blogspot.in/p/a-simple-script-to-gethardware-info.html)

Thanks,
Mssm

Answer (score 0):

The `hw-probe` tool collects outputs of most popular hardware listers (hwinfo, dmidecode, lspci, etc.): https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxhw/hw-probe/

Probe example: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=0b29192f95

[image]

I'm the author of this project, feel free to ask any questions in comments!