# Integrated webcam not detected after update to 14.04

Tags: updates, webcam

Yesterday I updated my Thinkpad T530 from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 (both x64). Since then the integrated webcam is not working anymore. I tried to use it with Skype and Google Hangouts, but it says that no video device is found. I found some solutions but they did not work. 
First thing I did was to check if the integrated webcam is activated in bios settings. Then I found this "[How can I get my webcam to work with Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457983/how-can-i-get-my-webcam-to-work-with-ubuntu-14-04)" but I don't have any /dev/video* device.

Can anybody tell me what to do? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried activating it using the function [Fn] keys on the laptop?

Comment: Yes, but it did not work.

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo && sudo modprobe uvcvideo`

Comment: Can you please provide the results of `lsusb`

Comment: user.dz, your solution didn't work for me

Comment: @user.dz your solution didn't work for me. I mean I hit that and no log is shown after that. As in nothing happened.

Comment: try checking the hardware user privileges in User and Groups administration

Answer (score 82):

I know that a long time passed since you posted.

with `lspci` get:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)`

The solution was to activate the webcam with the keys: `fn` + `CAM`  in my case `f10`.

I hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: `fn` + `CAM` (`f10`) also worked for my integrated web cam.

Comment: Kind of embarrassingly simple, but that worked for me, too.

Comment: Wtf just happened. That worked! LOL

Comment: Uff, that was simple

Comment: there is no camera button on my laptop.

Comment: Note: after you press the camera button (e.g. fn + F10) , you may need to restart the application in order for the application to recognize the webcam.  This was the case with `cheese` for me.

Comment: If your notebook doesn't have that camera-enable button, you can try to disable and re-enable the setting in the BIOS.

Comment: FN+F6 for me (MSI laptop). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 37):

I finally figured this out. For the longest time, I just thought the web camera in my laptop was broken. It didn't even show up when doing an `lsusb` ...and it won't, because hitting the web camera function key on the laptop **adds/removes the device in hardware as if it has been physically connected/disconnected**.

You must hit `Fn+<Camera Key>` on your keyboard and then you'll see the following in your kernel logs:

`[22219.057985] msi_wmi: Unknown event received
[22219.509572] usb 3-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[22219.646222] usb 3-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=055c
[22219.646229] usb 3-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[22219.646233] usb 3-1.4: Product: BisonCam, NB Pro
[22219.646237] usb 3-1.4: Manufacturer: Generic
[22219.646239] usb 3-1.4: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[22219.649336] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device BisonCam, NB Pro (5986:055c)
[22219.652486] input: BisonCam, NB Pro as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.4/3-1.4:1.0/input/input19`

Here is what the key looks like on my MSI WS-60. It varies from laptop to laptop. Hit it and you should watch `/dev/video0` appear and disappear.

[image: Photo of an MSI WS-60 Keyboard's Web Camera Function Key]

Comment: Thanks!  I also have an MSI laptop.  Looking at that icon now, I can see how it sorta looks like a camera.  But before this, I thought it was something to do with a monitor.  They need a better icon!

Comment: what the actual f***. why does this button exist!? thanks for the fix, saved me!

Comment: Hahaha, have the same keyboard you do. Thanks for that. Had no idea what that button actually was ;)

Comment: Can't thank you enough!  how sneaky.  I must have hit this key combination by accident at some point without noticing it (and if I had noticed it I wouldn't have known what it was for ;-)

Comment: The issue was frustrating, but the fact that the switch is at the hardware rather than the software level is an excellent security feature

Comment: Thank you so much for the screenshot! I'd have never known about this button otherwise. :D

Comment: lol i took my laptop to 4 people no one knew what is the problem and then they told me that the camera is broken

Answer (score 14):

Install webcam driver packages and needed software

```
sudo apt-get install cheese build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: You are awesome! thanks for the command. I just used it and my Skype video back to normal functionality.

Comment: run above command but not working for ubuntu 16.04 :(

Comment: works for me for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: `apt-get install cheese` was sufficient on my ancient HP notebook running 16.04, after that all applications could find the webcam.

Comment: worked in ubuntu 18.04 / lenovo laptop as well. Thanks !

Comment: does not work with Macbook white Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: can't find package `linux-headers-uname -r`

Answer (score 10):

For proud owners of the Asus Zenbook!

My camera did not work after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.
So I ran `sudo apt-get install guvcview` and restarted my computer. And it works now! Refer to this guide for further questions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook#Webcam

Comment: also worked for my System76 machine after upgrading to 18.04 =)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install guvcview`, followed by `modprobe uvcvideo` (which may not have been necessary), followed by reboot, followed by `Func+F6`, followed by `cheese` worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  `Func+F6` now toggles access to built-in webcam on/off.  What I still don't understand:  Why installing `guvcview` was needed now when the webcam worked without it for approx 5-1/2 of the 6 years I've had this machine.

Answer (score 5):

[The comment by user.dz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04/1199948#comment643476_461657) on the original question provided the solution worked for me:

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo && sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `GTK UVC video viewer` . This software is available in `software center`. Then go to `Videos` and select the `device`. I have two device connected with my computer. I keep my mobile device active, because of that in device it is showing `Symphony FT45`. In your case chose the `default device`. This might solve your problem. Have fun.

[image].

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem - it will probably be solved when you update and upgrade your computer.

try this command:

```
lsmod
```

In this screen you'll find the devicename, its number, the third column means that your device activated or not (0 means not activated). See screenshot below:

[image]

To activate this device use this command :

```
modprobe <name of the device>
```

your kernel will run the activate automatically after rebooting.

You can also do it manually through this file `/etc/rc.d/rc.modules`

Comment: which one is the webcam??

Comment: I suppose uvcvideo is camera and it's not working for me. It's still showing 0.

Comment: /etc/rc.d/rc.modules works!

Comment: I have two laptops where it says 0 for uvcvideo, but the camera on video works on one but not the other.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Lenovo Ideapad Y500, elementaryOS) installing the following packages solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libsbigudrv2 libsbigudrv0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your display manager on Mint from **mdm**, to **lightdm** your sound and video won't work. I tried everything on any website but nothing worked. I just reverted back to **mdm** from **lightdm** and sound-video-webcam was back and running fine.

Comment: @mr_azad, You write, "Then go to Videos and select the device." I do not see anything that says "videos", please correct this.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into an issue where the integrated webcam was not detected (no /dev/video*), with similar symptoms to the 'disable camera button' responses above. My work laptop does not have that button, but there is a BIOS setting to enable the camera, which was off.

I restarted and entered Bios Setup (F12) and for me the setting was under:
System Configuration > Miscellaneous Devices > Enable Camera

I didn't know this option even existed, hopefully this post saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a physical switch somewhere on your laptop if there is no key combination or BIOS setting to kill the camera. On my machine, HP Spectre x360 Convertible 15-df1xxx, this was a tiny, miniature, unnoticeable switch right next to the USB port. Seems I had accidentally bumped into it while upgrading the Ubuntu version using a USB stick. Seeing no key combo or BIOS option and finding no software fix, I was pretty convinced this was caused by the kernel upgrade. Double check your hardware before you file a bug report; you might get surprised!