# Webcam not detected in cheese, also not listed in lsusb

Tags: 14.04, dell, webcam, cheese

I have dell inspiron n5110 laptop with windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 installed in it. Webcam works fine in windows. But in ubuntu , cheese shows "no device found". Here is my output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I tried installing the drivers by typing :

```
sudo apt-get install cheese build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Still the problem remains the same.
I tried `sudo chmod 777 /dev/video*`
It says:

`chmod: cannot access ‘/dev/video*’: No such file or directory`

Now I tried all available solutions but no had luck. Currently it seems that this is an unsolved problem.

Comment: check your spelling of the file names at the chmod command

Comment: This answer helped me. Makes sense to check this out if you come to this page: https://askubuntu.com/a/695609/359806

Answer (score 0):

**Uninstall cheese and config files:**

sudo apt-get --purge remove cheese

**Reinstall cheese:**

sudo apt-get install cheese

**Reboot your computer**

This works perfectly for a Dell Notebook using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: OBS: Dell with Dual boot Windows 10 - Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

- Open up your terminal application (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).
- Open your grub configuration file for editing as root:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/default/grub
  ```
- Change the line that reads:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash
  ```

  to read:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
  ```
- Save the file and exit the text editor. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>)
- Update grub:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Restart/Reboot your computer.

Comment: This approach does not work for me.

Comment: I got trouble with this approach, pc stuck in acpi error. Finally I have to boot with live usb disk and revert back the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I know maybe a stupid answer...
If you have dual booted Windows and Ubuntu in your system and if accidentally you disabled camera (F6) in Windows (atleast for MSI Laptops) it affects Ubuntu as well. So just go back to Windows and enable it, and hopefully it works now.

Answer (score -1):

I saw this post from [LinuxMint forum](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=170425)

- Unload the uvcvideo module

  ```
  sudo rmmod uvcvideo
  ```
- Reload the module with the quirks parameter set to 0x100

  ```
  sudo modprobe uvcvideo quirks=0x100
  ```
- Cheese app still crash.
- Try at http://www.testwebcam.com/
- Allow when Google Chrome asked.
- Enable when Flash plugin asked.