# How to install webcam (camera) driver on Ubuntu 17.04? (No device found)

Tags: drivers, 17.04, webcam, camera, cheese

My laptop can't detect my webcam anymore, so I can't take pictures or see myself from the webcam.

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and everything was OK..., until I decided to install 17.04.  After installing 17.04, I was faced with this problem.

In 16.04, I didn't have to install a webcam driver or anything like that.  The webcam worked fine.

In 17.04, when I try to access the webcam in Cheese, it just shows a black window that says:

> No device found

See below:

[image: screenshot of Cheese]

So I decided to install the webcam driver.

I searched, but couldn't find any useful codes to install the driver...

My laptop: MSI GE62 6QD - C

I have no idea how to fix that...

`lsusb` output in terminal:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 1a81:2218 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1770:ff00  
Bus 001 Device 032: ID 2001:7d05 D-Link Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 025: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And the output from this command:`dmesg | tail -50`:

```
[16308.268505] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
[16308.268519] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
[16308.268532] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
[16308.268545] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
[16308.268558] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
[16308.268571] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
[17433.149263] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[17500.121107] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[17500.121181] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[18004.910851] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[18207.354122] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[19406.810520] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[19406.811776] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[20400.209203] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[20400.210265] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[20641.822528] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[21826.543193] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[21826.543205] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[22679.670816] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[22679.671764] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[23279.386485] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[23880.191014] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[24032.727843] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[24416.177587] perf: interrupt took too long (2504 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[24633.161446] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[26263.567534] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[26628.114101] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[26628.115135] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[27045.349348] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[29153.102916] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[30029.096423] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[30520.050896] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[30520.051450] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[30636.247042] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[31120.997150] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[31772.176166] perf: interrupt took too long (3133 > 3130), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63750
[32240.710930] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[32240.712033] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[32798.864071] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[33076.457006] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[33127.857923] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[33675.255998] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[34067.398591] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[34067.399598] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[34276.412887] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[34276.413960] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[34339.037218] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[34833.346182] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[35519.442761] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[36893.127001] cdc_ether 1-4:1.0 enx54b80aecb661: kevent 12 may have been dropped
```

`lspci -k` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] HD Graphics 530
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H SMBus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

`lsmod` output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
hid_generic            16384  0
ccm                    20480  2
rfcomm                 77824  2
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               462848  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
bbswitch               16384  0
bnep                   20480  2
mxm_wmi                16384  0
msi_wmi                16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 msi_wmi
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             200704  0
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  4
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_usb_ms
arc4                   16384  2
snd_hda_codec_realtek    90112  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
iwlmvm                368640  0
rndis_host             16384  0
cdc_ether              16384  1 rndis_host
usbnet                 45056  2 rndis_host,cdc_ether
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
mac80211              782336  1 iwlmvm
mii                    16384  1 usbnet
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
iwlwifi               229376  1 iwlmvm
snd                    77824  20 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
cfg80211              602112  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
hci_uart               98304  0
btbcm                  16384  2 hci_uart,btusb
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                16384  2 hci_uart,btusb
wmi                    16384  2 msi_wmi,mxm_wmi
bluetooth             557056  33 btrtl,hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_acpi
acpi_pad              180224  0
acpi_als               16384  0
tpm_crb                16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
industrialio           69632  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
nvidia_uvm            647168  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               36864  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               20480  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
usbhid                 53248  0
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  1 uas
i915                 1449984  3
nvidia_drm             45056  2
nvidia_modeset        790528  6 nvidia_drm
nvidia              12304384  99 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        151552  2 i915,nvidia_drm
psmouse               139264  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
alx                    45056  0
ahci                   36864  2
drm                   352256  6 i915,nvidia_drm,drm_kms_helper
mdio                   16384  1 alx
libahci                32768  1 ahci
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  0
video                  40960  2 msi_wmi,i915
i2c_hid                20480  0
pinctrl_intel          20480  1 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
hid                   114688  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
fjes                   73728  0
```

How can I fix this?

**Question updated**:

I have 2 Unclassified devices in output of `hwinfo --usb`:

```
06: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: X7GA.gra4j3_XRdD
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-7:1.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "MSI EPF USB"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1770 "MSI EPF USB"
  Device: usb 0xff00 "MSI EPF USB"
  Revision: "1.10"
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v1770pFF00d0110dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc00ip00in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: usbhid is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe usbhid"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #8 (Hub)

07: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: WYZM.jlWSV9fCQK4
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-12:1.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Realtek RTS5129 Card Reader Controller"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x0bda "Realtek Semiconductor Corp."
  Device: usb 0x0129 "RTS5129 Card Reader Controller"
  Revision: "39.60"
  Driver: "rtsx_usb"
  Driver Modules: "rtsx_usb"
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v0BDAp0129d3960dcFFdscFFdpFFicFFisc06ip50in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: rtsx_usb is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe rtsx_usb"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #8 (Hub)
```

The output says that both of the drivers are active.

I tried all these commands for activation:

```
modprobe rtsx_usb
modprobe usbhid
```

then i tried with sudo too:

```
sudo modprobe rtsx_usb
sudo modprobe usbhid
```

Nothing happened!

Output of ls /dev/video*

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

Cheese software doesn't work!(No device found)

Comment: Your laptop specifications would help.

Comment: @George like which specifications?

Comment: Boot a 16.04 live image, and compare the output of `lsusb` there if it works, to the output of `lsusb` in 17.04. Check that the camera shows up in both places. Also compare the `lsmod` output in both.

Comment: Did you find your problem? I've the same.. :/

Comment: there are many things that could be happening, but from the linked answers, if `/dev/video*` is not showing up, perhaps there is an fn key that enables/disables the camera, as per: https://askubuntu.com/a/695609/17060 Also, as a troubleshooting tip, one can run `vlc` and select "Open Capture" and see if you can access the webcam live feed using this; if so, then the problem may be webcam application configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Try to press [fn] + [F?] on your laptop keyboard

? in my case (Fujitsu Lifebook) is F12 (with camera icon)

Comment: This may be an unorthodox answer but it actually worked for me on my MSI GF63 laptop, thanks!

Comment: Don't know why it would be called unorthodox, but this worked perfectly on my MSI GL72 6QF with Ubuntu 18.04 as well. Saved me a looot of time judging from all the output the original poster added to their question.