# Integrated webcam not working on Lenovo Yoga 510 (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: lenovo, skype, webcam

I have installed Ubuntu Bionic Beaver on my Lenovo Yoga 510 Laptop.

I need Skype, but my webcam does not work. It seems not to be recognized.
Cheese does not work either: "No Device Found"

My `lsusb` result is this:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e360 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 3938:1031  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg | grep cam` shows nothing, as does `dmesg | grep video`.

What can I do?

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks a lot! At Lenovo laptop, just press the F8 key, When it pressed, the hardware is activated.