# Lenovo ThinkPad T470s: Internal Camera not detected in Ubuntu 18.04.5 (but it is on different T470s)

Tags: 18.04, camera

The problem is stated in the headline: Neither Cheese nor any other service that uses the built-in camera can detect it on my private laptop.
There is also no `/dev/video0`.

Weirdly enough, my work laptop is the same model with the exact same Ubuntu version and exact same kernel version. Here the cam works and `/dev/video0` is present.

I have tried all advice posted for similar questions, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062331/integrated-webcam-not-working-after-upgrade-to-18-04) and [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224374/integrated-webcam-not-working-ubuntu-18-04), i.e. I

- Ran `sudo apt-get install cheese build-essential linux-headers-'uname -r'`
- Checked for physical switches to activate the cam (there are no FN buttons concerning the cam on T470s)
- Checked in the BIOS that the cam is enabled
- Ran the usual `sudp apt update && sudo apt install upgrade`

Nothing helped. When I run `hwinfo` on the work laptop, I see a device called `video0`, more detailed `usb-Bison_Integrated_Camera_20090101001-video-index0`, which is not present on the private machine. I guess the is the device, but I have not found any linux drivers for it.

What else could I do to get the camera working?

Comment: Please look in your bios/efi if there is something related to camera.