# Built-in Webcam not detected, also no /dev/video* in Ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04

Tags: video, hp, webcam

I just upgraded to 20.04 and my camera still does not work. As title says, the Webcam is not detected, also there is no /dev/video*. I am using a HP ENVY13.
I tried many solutions from previous posts (most are similar to this [Integrated webcam not detected after update to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04)), and nothing worked so far. I tried the camera key (f4 in my case), reinstalling cheese, reinstalling uvcvideo and nothing.

Here is some initial input:

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00c9 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:0a8f Logitech, Inc. Logitech USB Headset
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 062a:5918 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9b41 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f9
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f0
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f5
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02e8
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02e9
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02e0
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b8 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02bc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02a4
06:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108BM [GeForce MX250] (rev a1)
10:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSDPEKNW020T8 [660p, 2TB] (rev 03)
```

I have no idea how to go from here. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: try checking the hardware user privileges in User and Groups administration

Comment: @cabpacedilla Just be a little cautious with copying and pasting the same query to multiple different questions.

Answer (score 5):

I also ran into an issue where the integrated webcam was not detected (no /dev/video*), and tried the answers in the post you linked. My work laptop does not have that button, but there is a BIOS setting to enable the camera, which was off.

I restarted and entered Bios Setup (F12) and for me the setting was under:
System Configuration > Miscellaneous Devices > Enable Camera

I didn't know this option even existed, might be something to check on your system.

Comment: Hmm not sure then, my first step was to work through the solutions in the link posted above, this was just the fix that ended up working for me.