# Cheese captures long, corrupted videos

Tags: video, webcam, cheese, desktop-recording

### Problem

When I try to capture a video on my Thinkpad T495s laptop (Ubuntu 21.10) with Cheese, it produces a long video that freezes at the first frame. How can I fix this problem? Feel free to ask for more information if that helps.

### Screenshots

1. This is what it looks like when I open Cheese
   [image]
2. Right after I press the record button, the time jumps to random number
   [image]
3. And the resulting video will either freeze on the first frame (like taking a picture) or completely green (see below)
   [image]

## Related

These are several similar reports of the issue I found on Google

1. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1884260
2. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/cheese/-/issues/79

Comment: First, make sure the following packages are installed: `sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly`

Comment: I tried again after I installed those packages, but the results were the same: the videos froze and the length of the videos were still weirdly long.

Comment: Okay. The other option is to install guvcview: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install guvcview` Then, run `guvcview` . If you need to, kill guvcview and then stop and start the uvcvideo module and try guvcview again. `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo` and `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` . If this works, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: There's also an [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/836471/167115) that refers to a lenovo laptop that suggests installing a couple of packages.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting an alternative webcam app, but my question is intended to find a way to fix Cheese, since I would still prefer using the native app from Ubuntu.

Comment: As for the link you provided, the packages suggested there did not fix the problem sadly.

Comment: I've had the same problem. Recording a 30 second video will result in a 5h45m30s video. There will be audio at the beginning of the video, and video at the end. Cheese is incompatible with Ubuntu 21.10 on Lenovo Thinkpads, possibly others as well. It doesn't matter what the webcam source it; internal cam or external, same behavior.