# "/etc" directory is missing or corrupted in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, webcam, system, etc, data-corruption

Hello fellows Ubuntu users ! I hope this is not a duplicate but I need help on my computer. Since I switched from Kubuntu to Ubuntu (both 20.04 LTS), I keep having issues with this computer. I thought everything was repaired today when I wanted to start my camera on Discord and it didn't show up, I then had a look at the settings of Discord and saw no camera device. I then checked on the internet what was my issue and i couldn't resolve it.

I then tried this command :
`lsmod`
and saw the device was existing as toshiba_apci (I tried a lot of things before) but nothing showed up again in an app like GUVCView or Cheese.

I already rebooted multiple times and still no camera.

I saw on this thread : ([Integrated webcam not detected after update to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04)) that i needed to use the file "/etc/rc.d/rc.modules" but when i tried to cd in the terminal i got a "No such file or directory error"

I then looked at Files and went into /system and i saw a red cross on the /etc directory just like this :
[Broken Directory Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95m6b.png)
and i clicked on it and it said this :
[The link "/etc" is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUebo.png)

I think my computer is corrupted but that means that i may have issues again with drivers and this would be the second dead pc in the same week :/

Thanks if someone can find the way to help me !

All my regards to you guys

Comment: How exactly did you "switch" from Kubuntu to Ubuntu Desktop? What does the webcam have to do with this question?  If you have multiple problems, you should ask them separately.

Comment: I did it the way Ubuntu website intended it i guess. this link could maybe provide you infos : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/migration_vers_ubuntu (sry its in french) and i downloaded ubuntu while running the comp without a reboot because i did it in class

Comment: /etc is not a link, there is no /system, and I am confused by what you said.

Comment: I doubt your install could run without /etc, so something strange is going on.

Comment: If anyone wants to see what in the hell is my system folder i kinda think it's broken :| [link](https://imgur.com/vmS9ige)

Comment: That looks like it might be related to an anbox installation - nothing to do with your host Ubuntu system

Comment: No idea what that "326 MB Volume" is, but it's definitely not "your system folder" in any conventional sense of the word. First, 326 MB is much too little to contain your system, and second, Ubuntu would never offer an "eject" button for a drive where the system itself resides.

Comment: I would have just reinstalled the operating system. Changing the desktop environment on an installed system can get messy. When all else fails, that's the defacto solution.

Comment: @Nmath i did that and yes i think this was the only solution my computer was really corrupted