# Integrated webcam isnt working at all ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: drivers, 14.04, skype, webcam, cheese

i've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64 and cheese isn't working also skype
they're recognizing the camera but it shows an error on playing from it

i tried solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04) , [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457983/how-can-i-get-my-webcam-to-work-with-ubuntu-14-04) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477424/why-do-cheese-dont-work-in-14-04-amd-64)
and also no one worked for me

i have the file `/dev/video0` and i tried

> sudo chmod 777 /dev/video*

and

> vlc v4l2:////dev//video0

but that's didnt work neither 
,
also i tried to install guvcview but also didnt work

the output of dmesg is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7652190/) , and the output of lsusb is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7652135/)

and also it was working at initial install

any thoughts please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Webcam driver packages :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

If already installed them, reconfigure them:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: its already installed, and gives the error on second commnad

Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-53-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.