# Ubuntu doesn't detect webcam

Tags: webcam, msi

Cheese just doesn't detect the webcam .. nor other software. This is an MSI GT70 2PC. I cannot even find someone having the problem. The webcam even works fine on windows 8.1 .

I also tried adding the user to the video group and I even tried this:

`sudo chmod 777 /dev/video*`

following [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457983/how-can-i-get-my-webcam-to-work-with-ubuntu-14-04) but ubuntu can't find the directory in the first place!

Answer (score 33):

Maybe the camera is locked. I own a MSI GS70-2PC-210US and from time to time this happens to me after doing updates.

Try pressing **<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>** (or whatever the camera lock/unlock button is located on your keyboard).

Comment: that was the problem. Thanks

Comment: same, bravo. after all the problems i had with the audio drivers where i have to console type alsadriver every time to hear the speakers i was expecting the worst scenario

Comment: Wow, would have never tried that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: That worked for me too. On my MSI GE66 Raider, it's Fn + F4

Answer (score 0):

Try going on "additional drivers" (you can search for it on the Ubuntu search engine) and looking for any proprietary drivers for your device. It usually works for me.