# Error in running webcam using Cheese application on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, webcam, camera, cheese

When I open the Cheese application in Ubuntu 18.04 I get this error message:

```
There was an error playing a video from the webcam.
```

Comment: Please include more details like your system name, configuration, etc. Is it a thinkpad? If yes, [it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04) may help.

Comment: my laptop is Toshiba-satellite c55-c1665 and my operating system is Ubuntu 18.04,   what's configuration should i mention ??

Comment: First of all lets determine your WebCam. First of all run `sudo apt install v4l-utils`.
Then `sudo apt-get install v4l-utils` and paste the output of latter in question.

Comment: i had installed this package and get ("No device  found") when i open cheese

Comment: This may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/457983/how-can-i-get-my-webcam-to-work-with-ubuntu-14-04 and this https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04/

Comment: when i type this commend line ($ ls -ltrh /dev/video*)
get (ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory) may help to detect the problem

Comment: also run this($ dmesg | tail -n 20) 
#get this ---[ end trace bcdefccb35bfff8a ]---
[  973.566335] media: media_devnode_register: cdev_device_add failed
[  973.566440] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  973.566442] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)

Comment: please help i need open CV to complete my project by this way i can't pass this year of college

Comment: Try app like Skype or try Ubuntu in Live mode abd test the same. I am afraid that your camera is broken.

Comment: yah maybe it was broken anyway thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

You can try uninstalling and reinstalling Cheese.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove cheese
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

Comment: nothing happened give me the same error massage