# How to check HDD info technical?

Tags: 14.04, hardware, disk

How can I check the technical info on my notebook with Ubuntu 14.04?

I would like to check the dimension and if is IDLE or SATA

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143796/how-to-determine-hardware will show all you can get from the operating system.

Comment: @Rinzwind: A more specialised utility `hdparm` was not mentioned in that thread and has been used as an answer here. Arguable this is the best tool for a look at the HDD only.

Answer (score 1):

The utility `hdparm` is IMHO the best tool for this job. Simply run as follows:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

and you will have more than enough information on your HDD. There are many options available (see in the reference at the base of this post), I have given:

```
-I   Detailed/current information directly from drive
```

`hdparm` is part of a default installation on Trusty Tahr so no extra installation required...

**References:**

- [hdparm man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/hdparm.8.html)